# How to display Navigation Bar for MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, xcode, navigation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a movie that plays in MPMovieplayerViewcontroller in fullscreen on clicking a button. But the MPMoviePlayerViewController does not display navigation bar on the top. How to make the navigation bar visible as the movie is played?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPMoviePlayerViewcontroller` is a standard `UIViewController`, so just present it as the rootViewController of a `UINavigationController`

i.e.

instead of

```
[self presentViewController:myMoviePlayerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

do:

```
UINavigationController *movieNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myMoviePlayerViewController];
[self presentViewController:movieNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```